# Force re-create tables with AWS Amplify GraphQL/DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

Is there a way I can force re-creation of tables with AWS Amplify GraphQL API?

Accidentally deleted some development tables and have no idea how to re-create them now.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I ran into the same issue. Thanks

Comment: No, I had to fix them by hand in the end.